# Websocket does not receive a message from django channels server even though they are connected

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am currently building an application with django channels.
I have a websocket connected to a server. Looking at my terminal, it seems like the websocket is successfully connected to the server.

> ```
> HTTP GET / 200 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:62087]
> HTTP GET /static/video/js/websocket.js 200 [0.00, 127.0.0.1:62087]
> WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/video [127.0.0.1:62089]
> WebSocket CONNECT /ws/video [127.0.0.1:62089]
> ```

However, the websocket does not receive the message sent from the server.

Here are my codes:
**consumers.py**

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

class VideoConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        self.send(json.dumps({'message': 'you are connected!'}))
```

**websocket.js**

```
const address = 'ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/video'
const websocket = new WebSocket(address)

const btn = document.getElementById('myButton')

websocket.onopen = (event) => {
  console.log('websocket connected!!!')
}

websocket.onmessage = (event) => {
  console.log(event.data)
}
```

I would like to receive the message "you are connected!" on my browser's console.
I looked into the official django channels document and google searched for a solution but I failed to solve my issue. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had nothing to do with the codes above.
I have solved the issue by editing my **asgi.py** under the project folder.

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
import video.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'VideoChat.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        'http': get_asgi_application(),
        'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(video.routing.websocket_urlpatterns))
        )
    }
)
```

As you can see, I have wrapped the `AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(video.routing.websocket_urlpatterns))` with `AllowedHostsOriginValidator`. After I removed the `AllowedHostsOriginValidator` like `'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(video.routing.websocket_urlpatterns))`, the issue was solved perfectly.

p.s: I have noticed that the websocket can still be connected with the previous setting. It just neither send a message nor receive a message from the server.